# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined react

Tags: javascript, css

i am getting below error when use style in my react code

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

i try to call the showSlides function . Error throws in style.

```
slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

code is :

```
showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {this.slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  this.slideIndex++;
  if (this.slideIndex > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(this.showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds  
}
```

any syntax change in react js

Comment: @MaheerAli: added

Comment: `slides` must be an empty array... so gives an error

Comment: What's unclear in the error message? The object you are trying to reference `slides[this.slideIndex-1]` does not exist, you cannot invoke a method upon non-existing variable. This has nothing to do with react.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: is  slides[this.slideIndex-1] check this first